# Does changing dojo.dnd.Source.checkAcceptance to true affect type checking?

Tags: dojo

I've got a working DnD implementation however I've run into a snag. It seems that if I set dojo.dnd.Source.checkAcceptance to true, the Source container I do that to stops checking the dndType, it accepts everything.

I'm checking if there is a node present in the dojo.dnd.Source container, if there is I want to disable dropping. I do this twice because if content is already present when the page loads, we want to disable dropping additional content there and only allow the Source container to contain 1 node. Likewise for the onDrop event.

If checkAcceptance = false, then that works and doesn't accept any drops, however if checkAcceptance = true then it accepts everything.

I'm using dojo version 1.4.2.

Here's the offending code:

```
var contentSourceA = new dojo.dnd.Source("ContentCol",{accept: ["contentItem"]});  
if (dojo.query("#ContentCol")[0].children.length > 1) {  
    contentSourceA.checkAcceptance = function(){return false;}  
}else{  
    contentSourceA.checkAcceptance = function(){return true;}  
}  
dojo.connect(contentSourceA,'onDrop',function(source,node,copy){  
    if (dojo.query("#ContentCol")[0].children.length > 1) {  
        contentSourceA.checkAcceptance = function(){return false;}  
    }else{  
        contentSourceA.checkAcceptance = function(){return true;}  
    }  
});
```

So hence my question: Does changing dojo.dnd.Source.checkAcceptance affect the type checking functionality? If not, what have I done wrong here? Should I do this via one of the Topic events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type checking logic is encapsulated in the default implementation of `dojo.dnd.Source.checkAcceptance` function. If you override this function, the default logic is lost.

You can create your own DnD source class by inheriting `dojo.dnd.Source`:

```
dojo.declare("AcceptOneItemSource", dojo.dnd.Source, {
    checkAcceptance : function(source, nodes) {
       if (this.node.children.length > 1) {
           return false;
       }
       return this.inherited(arguments);
    }
});
```